# Redirecting /users/me to /me on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have just got my web app working with usernames being like this:  `http://myapp.com/dean` instead of `http://myapp.com/users/dean`.

How do I go about redirecting the `/users/` to their username?

This is what my routes.rb file looks like (not the pages, etc):

```
resources :users
resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]

match ':id'         => 'users#show'
```

Removing the `resources :users` breaks the site completely and shows `No route matches` errors.

Comment: Try to add :path => '' to resources :users: `resources :users, :path => ''`

Comment: @Hck that works straight away and after a bit of moving around in the routes file, all the pages work as well. Could you post this as an answer and I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add :path => '' to resources :users:

```
resources :users, :path => ''
```

Answer (score 0):

`match "/users/:name" => redirect("/%{name}")`

well anyway I believe you're the one who decides which links to use so you might do sth like

```
match ':id' => 'users#show', :as => :sometwhere
```

and later in your views use

```
link_to somewhere_path( @user.name )
```

instead of

```
link_to user_path( @user )
```

Comment: OK I've done that and it works. It show's `/users/dean` in the navigation bar. How would I change that? Is it easy or should I just keep it like that?

Comment: I can't say for sure but I suppose it can't be fixed/changed cause it shows value of the `href` attribute

Comment: What for do you need routes like `/users/:name` ?

Comment: Well it was set like that but I want now just the `/dean` to show instead. It's not a problem, it's just some foreign characters are showing 500 errors.